# Error when copying data from Pandas Dataframe to Amazon RedShift table

Tags: database, python-3.x, postgresql, pandas

I am trying to write a Pandas Dataframe to a Amazon Redshift DB. Given below is the code I am using.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import psycopg2 
import io

engine=create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@host:port/database')
conn=engine.raw_connection()
cur = conn.cursor()
output = io.StringIO()
report.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=False, index=False)
output.seek(0)
contents = output.getvalue()
cur.copy_from(output, table_name, null="")   
conn.commit()
```

However on running the above code, i get the below error

```
NameError: name 'database' is not defined
```

Could anyone help. Thanks..

Comment: What line does the traceback refer to raising the exception?

Comment: Hi Ludo, I managed to sort this by using the below code

conn = create_engine('postgresql://user:pass@host:port/datbase')
df.to_sql('table', conn, index = False, if_exists = 'replace')

In between I am trying to Amazon RedShift Table..

Answer (score 0):

Used the below code to copy Df to Amazon Redshift Table

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
conn = create_engine('postgresql://user:pass@host:port/datbase') 
df.to_sql('table', conn, index = False, if_exists = 'replace')
```